# prolog - manual meanings

Tags: prolog

I've read the manual from swi-prolog:

```
union(+Set1, +Set2, -Set3)
```

what do + and - mean ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They indicate whether each argument should be instantiated at input or gets instantiated upon returning from that predicate.

- '+' means that the argument should be instantiated when calling that predicate.
- '-' means that the argument returns instantiated  when returning from the predicate

For the union predicate, you should call it with Set1 and Set2 instantiated, and on return Set3 will get instantiated.

Comment: +1. For completeness, these are called *mode annotations*, since a variable's instantiated v. uninstantiated state is called its *mode* (which is orthogonal to its type).